# ASP.NET MVC 6 Change Default Url Redirect When Not Logged In

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-authorization, asp.net-authentication

I have a mvc project in developemnt, when a user isn't logged in and trys to go to a page that ISN'T the login or register (AllowAnonymous) they're automatcally redirected to ~/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F"PageTryingToAccess".This is done via a authorization needed statement on the Program.cs.

My login page is the ~/home/(index), the default page on the (portal) website. Is there a way of overiding the ~/Account/Login default? I can not find where this is declared in the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way of overiding the ~/Account/Login default?

In .net6, you can add below code in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(opts =>
{
    opts.LoginPath = "/Home/Index";
   
});
```

In asp.net core3, you can use below:

```
 services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(opts =>
            {
                opts.LoginPath = "/Home/Index";                    
            });
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, tested and works. Thought there must be a setting to write in Program.cs, you saved me so much searching time!

Comment: Hi @rgh, any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer? If not, could you please follow up to let me know? Refer to:[How to access an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) Thanks.